# Question about pointers in Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone

In a `global.h` file I declare

```
dataManager *IdataManager;
```

Then later when the program initializes I allocate and initialize the variable, and use it in several different views as a means of accessing a set of data that gets downloaded when the app starts up.

Recently I noticed when I pull up one of my views, close it, and then open it again, I get a crash when trying to access the global `IdataManager`.

I finally came to the conclusion that it's contents were being released somehow by the view being de-initialized. I looked at the only place I was using the variable:

```
CCandidate *currentCandidate = [IdataManager CurrentCandidate];
```

So I changed this to say:

```
CCandidate *currentCandidate = [[IdataManager CurrentCandidate] retain];
```

I wasn't sure how the retain keyword worked, but it sounded like if the view really was releasing my data, I should specify in the creation of this pointer that it should be retained.

This fixed the crashing, but I don't really understand why this happened. Does objective-c just always release pointers you created when you dealloc it's owner? I was under the impression I was simply storing a memory address and giving it the name currentCandidate.

CCandidate.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CCandidate : NSObject {
 int ID;
 NSString* FName;
 NSString* MName;
 NSString* LName;
 NSString* FullName;
 NSString* DOB;
 NSString* Occupation;
 NSString* Employer;
 NSString* Phone;
 NSString* Fax;
 NSString* Email;
 NSString* Website;
 NSString* Party;
 NSString* TwitterUName;
 NSString* TwitterHashTag;
 NSString* Biography;
 NSString* BiographyLink;
 NSString* co;
 NSString* cb;
 NSString* uo;
 NSString* ub;

}

- (id) init;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int ID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* FName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* MName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* LName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* FullName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* DOB;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Occupation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Employer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Fax;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Website;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Party;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* TwitterUName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* TwitterHashTag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Biography;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* BiographyLink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* co;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* cb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* uo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* ub;

@end
```

CCandidate.m:

```
#import "CCandidate.h"


@implementation CCandidate
@synthesize ID;
@synthesize FName;
@synthesize MName;
@synthesize LName;
@synthesize FullName;
@synthesize DOB;
@synthesize Occupation;
@synthesize Employer;
@synthesize Phone;
@synthesize Fax;
@synthesize Email;
@synthesize Website;
@synthesize Party;
@synthesize TwitterUName;
@synthesize TwitterHashTag;
@synthesize Biography;
@synthesize BiographyLink;
@synthesize co;
@synthesize cb;
@synthesize uo;
@synthesize ub;

-(id) init {
 self = [super init];
 ID = -1;
 return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Learn how to write a correct init-method: http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html

Comment: How are you initializing the global variable? I think it could be that this variable is autoreleased.

Comment: After a connectionDidFinishLoading callback I set:    IdataManager = [[dataManager alloc] initWithData:receivedData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that it crashes when you access `IdataManager`. This is *not* true. You're program crashes when you try to access the `CurrentCandidate` object you received using the following line:

```
// read about naming methods here: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php
CCandidate *currentCandidate = [IdataManager CurrentCandidate];
```

I suspect you're releasing `currentCandidate` somewhere you shouldn't. It works the first time because you get back an autoreleased object (You *musn't* release  those yourself!).

This is how it goes:

First time:

1. Get autoreleased `currentCandidate`.
   **retain count == 2**
2. <your code>
3. `[currentCandidate release]` or `[currentCandidate autorelease]`
   **retain count == 1**
4. <your code>
5. All autoreleased objects get released.
   **retain count == 0**
6. `currentCandidate` gets deallocated.

Second time:

1. Get autoreleased `currentCandidate`. This is an invalid object that has already been deallocated. -> CRASH.

---

If `[IdataManager CurrentCandidate`] *doesn't* return an autoreleased object as it should but instead just the pointer to the member of `IdataManager`, the code crashes later when accessing `currentCandidate`.

The fact that adding `retain` helps *proves* that you're releasing `currentCandidate` somewhere. Either directly, via autorelease or though some other algorithm. All classes from Apple *only* release objects that they've retained earlier on. Somewhere in your code there's an unbalanced `retain`/`release`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably release `currentCandidate` at the end of your method, or on deallocating your view.
Since you didn't retain the currentCandidate object, you shouldn' release it either!

Scan your code for something of the sorts: [currentCandidate release]

Make sure you read up on memory management. Its pretty important.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: The first thing I did was check for were I could have been releasing currentCandidate, it's not getting released.

Comment: Sorry, it is getting released, but there's no code releasing it, it's happening when I dealloc the view, which looks like this:

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

Comment: Can you give us the exact crash message that Xcode gives?
It looks like the CurrentCandidate isn't retained in the first place.
Can you post the code that initiates CurrentCandidate in IdataManager?
Do you have Garbage Collection enabled? (shouldn't matter, but still!)  "Project Settings -> Build -> search for 'garbage' "